# Perturbation theory in classical mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, perturbation-theory

We are familiar with perturbation theory in classical mechanics in the form of canonical perturbation theory and Lie transform theory. However, is there a perturbation theory within the Lagrangian framework? If so, can we briefly summarise how it looks; if there isn't, why not?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what kind of perturbation theory you're talking about.

There is a simple "equation-of-motion" perturbation theory, which starts with the equations of motion and then solves iteratively.  As the EoMs can usually be obtained using a Lagrangian, you have a *bona fide* Lagrangian perturbation theory.   A well-known technique is the [Poincare-Lindstedt method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Lindstedt_method).

For instance the solution to the EoM of a perturbed oscillator
\begin{align}
\ddot{x}+x+\epsilon x^3
\end{align}
is solved by expanding $x$ in powers of $\epsilon$ and expanding the frequency of oscillation $\omega$  in powers of $\epsilon$:
\begin{align}
x(t)&=x_0(t)+\epsilon x_1(t)+\ldots\, ,\\
\omega&=\omega_0+\epsilon \omega_1(t)+\ldots.
\end{align}
The expansion of $\omega$ is done to avoid so-called secular terms that appear (more or less systematically) in more direct (Fourier-based) approach.

The more canonical formalism is based on Hamilton-Jacobi theory, and uses action-angle variables as its starting point.  Again it is based on an expansion but this time the perturbative series in $\epsilon$ seeks to find a sequence of canonical transformations that will eliminate the new angle variable
\begin{align}
H(I,\theta)&\to K(J;\epsilon)\, ,\\
K(J;\epsilon)&=K_0(J)+\epsilon K_1(J)+\ldots
\end{align}
with an infinitesimal canonical transformation
\begin{align}
F_2(J,\phi)&=J\theta+\epsilon W^{(1)}(J,\theta)+\ldots\, ,\\
\phi&=\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial J}=\theta+\epsilon \frac{\partial W^{(1)}(J,\theta)}{\partial J}+\ldots
\end{align}
Sir Michael Berry has a good set of lecture notes on this in

> Berry, Michael Victor. "Regular and irregular motion." *AIP Conference proceedings*. Vol. 46. No. 1. American Institute of Physics, 1978.

and [available from his website.](https://michaelberryphysics.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/berry076.pdf)