# Is there a known method for decouple two coupled E.O.M. without making the interaction term to be 0?

Tags: interactions, differential-equations, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

I'm trying to evaluate the evolution of two scalar fields but their equations of motion are coupled via a potential term
$$ V(\phi, \psi) \supset \frac{1}{2}\lambda \phi^{2}\psi^{2}$$

From the lagrangian, the E.O.M are:

$$ \ddot{\phi} - 3H\dot{\phi} + m^{2}_{\phi}\phi - \lambda \phi \psi^{2} = 0  $$

$$ \ddot{\psi} - 3H\dot{\psi} + m^{2}_{\psi}\psi - \lambda \psi \phi^{2} = 0 $$

Wher H is the Hubble constant (although it depends on time, for my pourpose it can be set to a constant)
I'm looking for a closed solution or a way to decouple those eqs. avoiding the obvious $\lambda = 0$ situation.

Comment: Is the mass meant to be the same for both fields?

Comment: Nope, I'll edit though

Answer (score 2):

There is not always a way to decouple two fields. Here, I would expect that there probably is not a way to get an analytic solution for general $\lambda$. Generally such a thing is not possible, and I don't see any special structure that would let you remove this interaction in this case.

There are many approximation methods for this kind of interaction, particularly for small $\lambda$. You can develop a perturbative or iterative solution. You could also consider mean field theory if you need statistics of these fields. For general $\lambda$, you may need to integrate the equations numerically for given initial conditions and a range of $\lambda$ values.  Fortunately, this is an ODE, for which there are many relatively easy-to-use off the shelf solutions that should work.

Comment: Could you direct me to such references, @Andrew?

Comment: @IamZack This PSE answer gives a quick overview of classical perturbation theory: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/633063/perturbation-theory-in-classical-mechanics. Computing software like Mathematica, Matlab, and Python all have methods to solve ODEs that are fairly easy to use (probably best to ask at the stack exchange about the tool you are specifically interested in or search for documentation for those tools). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations) has an article on numerical methods. Runge-Kutta is a common one.

Comment: @IamZack Actually there is a way you could decouple the equations. You could take the equation $\ddot{\phi}+\cdots -\lambda \phi \psi^2= 0$, then solve that to get $\psi$ as a function $\phi$, $\dot{\phi}$, and $\ddot{\phi}$. Then plug the expression $\psi(\phi, \dot{\phi}, \ddot{\phi})$ into the other equation $\ddot{\psi}+\cdots=0$. Then, you will have a fourth-order non-linear ODE purely in terms of $\phi$. Solve this for $\phi$, then use your expression for $\psi=\psi(\phi, \dot{\phi}, \ddot{\phi})$ to get $\psi$. This method sounds hard, though, and you won't get an analytical solution.